# How can I use different error configurations for two CloudFront behaviors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I have a CloudFront distribution with a Custom Origin that points to an ALB on `/api/*` and an S3 Origin for a static site on all other paths (the distribution's default behavior). This servers a Vue application stored in S3 and an API running in Fargate that is load balanced by an ALB.

In the CloudFront distribution's error configuration, I have a rule that sends 404 responses to `/index.html` (this is required for SPA so that nested routes can by picked up by the javascript router). Currently when the API returns a 404 response, it is giving the `/index.html` response, not the 404 response from the API. This makes sense, but it is not the behavior I want. Is there a way to get the API 404 response on `/api/*`, but use `/index.html` as the 404 response only for the default S3 Origin/default behavior?

I originally had the ALB served on a subdomain, so this wasn't an issue. I'm trying to simplify things by serving the API and the frontend site on the same domain (`app.mydomain.com`) instead of serving the frontend on `mydomain.com` and the API on `api.mydomain.com`, but this has created a new bug with error responses.

I'm using CDK to build this application, here is the code I have for my CloudFront distribution that is causing the issue with 404 responses:

```py
        path_patterns = ["/api/*", "/admin/*"]
        self.distribution = cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(
            self,
            "CloudFrontDistribution",
            origin_configs=[
                cloudfront.SourceConfiguration(
                    custom_origin_source=cloudfront.CustomOriginConfig(
                        domain_name=alb,
                        origin_protocol_policy=cloudfront.OriginProtocolPolicy.MATCH_VIEWER,
                    ),
                    behaviors=[
                        cloudfront.Behavior(
                            allowed_methods=cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.ALL,
                            path_pattern=path_pattern,
                            forwarded_values={
                                "headers": ["*"],
                                "cookies": {"forward": "all"},
                                "query_string": True,
                            },
                        )
                        for path_pattern in path_patterns
                    ],
                ),
                cloudfront.SourceConfiguration(
                    s3_origin_source=cloudfront.S3OriginConfig(
                        s3_bucket_source=self.static_site_bucket
                    ),
                    behaviors=[
                        cloudfront.Behavior(
                            is_default_behavior=True,
                            cached_methods=cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.GET_HEAD,
                        )
                    ],
                ),
            ],
            alias_configuration=cloudfront.AliasConfiguration(
                acm_cert_ref=certificate.certificate_arn,
                names=[full_domain_name],
            ),
            error_configurations=[
                {
                    "errorCode": 403,
                    "errorCachingMinTtl": 0,
                    "responseCode": 200,
                    "responsePagePath": "/index.html",
                },
                {
                    "errorCode": 404,
                    "errorCachingMinTtl": 0,
                    "responseCode": 200,
                    "responsePagePath": "/index.html",
                },
            ],
        )
```

Edit: **2020-05-13**

I have tried removing the `error_configuration` from the `CloudFrontWebDistribution` and have also set `website_index_document` and `website_error_document` on the S3 Bucket:

```
        self.static_site_bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self,
            "StaticSiteBucket",
            access_control=s3.BucketAccessControl.PUBLIC_READ,
            bucket_name=f"{full_app_name}-frontend",
            removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            website_index_document="index.html",
            website_error_document="index.html",
        )
```

With this change I am still getting Key Error 404 responses, when I'm hoping to see the 404 page that my Vue app serves.

<s>Is it correct to use an S3 Origin in my CloudFront configuration for the static site, or should this be a custom origin that points to the bucket's website URL?</s>

I'm no using a custom origin for the ALB and the S3 Website. Here are all of the resources described in CDK:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_certificatemanager as acm,
    aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_cloudfront as cloudfront,
    aws_route53 as route53,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_route53_targets as targets,
    core,
)


class CloudFront(core.Construct):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: core.Construct,
        id: str,
        hosted_zone: route53.IHostedZone,
        certificate: acm.ICertificate,
        alb: str,
        full_domain_name: str,
        full_app_name: str,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        self.static_site_bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self,
            "StaticSiteBucket",
            access_control=s3.BucketAccessControl.PUBLIC_READ,
            bucket_name=f"{full_app_name}-frontend",
            removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            website_index_document="index.html",
            website_error_document="index.html",
        )

        self.policy_statement = iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=["s3:GetObject"],
            resources=[f"{self.static_site_bucket.bucket_arn}/*"],
        )

        self.policy_statement.add_any_principal()

        self.static_site_policy_document = iam.PolicyDocument(
            statements=[self.policy_statement]
        )

        self.static_site_bucket.add_to_resource_policy(self.policy_statement)

        path_patterns = ["/api/*", "/admin/*", "/flower/*"]
        self.distribution = cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(
            self,
            "CloudFrontDistribution",
            origin_configs=[
                cloudfront.SourceConfiguration(
                    custom_origin_source=cloudfront.CustomOriginConfig(
                        domain_name=alb,
                        origin_protocol_policy=cloudfront.OriginProtocolPolicy.MATCH_VIEWER,  # noqa
                    ),
                    behaviors=[
                        cloudfront.Behavior(
                            allowed_methods=cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.ALL,  # noqa
                            path_pattern=path_pattern,
                            forwarded_values={
                                "headers": ["*"],
                                "cookies": {"forward": "all"},
                                "query_string": True,
                            },
                        )
                        for path_pattern in path_patterns
                    ],
                ),
                cloudfront.SourceConfiguration(
                    custom_origin_source=cloudfront.CustomOriginConfig(
                        domain_name=self.static_site_bucket.bucket_domain_name,
                        origin_protocol_policy=cloudfront.OriginProtocolPolicy.MATCH_VIEWER,  # noqa
                    ),
                    behaviors=[
                        cloudfront.Behavior(
                            is_default_behavior=True,
                            cached_methods=cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.GET_HEAD,  # noqa
                        )
                    ],
                ),
            ],
            alias_configuration=cloudfront.AliasConfiguration(
                acm_cert_ref=certificate.certificate_arn,
                names=[full_domain_name],
            ),
        )

        route53.ARecord(
            self,
            "AliasRecord",
            target=route53.AddressRecordTarget.from_alias(
                targets.CloudFrontTarget(self.distribution)
            ),
            zone=hosted_zone.hosted_zone,
            record_name=f"{full_domain_name}.",
        )
```

Edit 2020-05-14

I was using the wrong domain name for the custom origin.  I tried `bucket_regional_domain_name` and `bucket_website_domain_name`, but these both give me `my-s3-bucket-name.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. Here's the the settings I used for the custom origin config:

```py
                cloudfront.SourceConfiguration(
                    custom_origin_source=cloudfront.CustomOriginConfig(
                        domain_name=f"{self.static_site_bucket.bucket_name}.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                        origin_protocol_policy=cloudfront.OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTP_ONLY,
                    ),
                    behaviors=[
                        cloudfront.Behavior(
                            is_default_behavior=True,
                            cached_methods=cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.GET_HEAD,
                        )
                    ],
                ),
```

`HTTP_ONLY` is important, this will not work with `MATCH_VIEWER`. Also, notice how I am using an f string to get the correct URL of the `s3-website` bucket. I'm still not sure if this is something I can find automatically in CDK. I'll update this if I find more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@briancaffey, I'm glad to help you again. It's not possible to do it in CloudFront. Alternatively, I *think* the following approach should work.

1. Delete custom error responses in CloudFront
2. Configure a custom error document in your S3 origin. [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html)]
3. Change CloudFront `S3Origin` to `CustomOrigin` with the S3 website endpoint set as the origin domain name.

Comment: Hi @jellycsc thank you for your answer. I have updated my `CloudFrontWebDistribution` resource with your suggested changes and I am now getting a 404 key error from S3. I updated the question with some additional notes. I'm going to try using a Custom Origin for the static site and I'll let you know if this works

Comment: @briancaffey Have you invalidated the CloudFront cache after this change?

Comment: I tried invalidating the cache after making your changes and also tried invalidating the cache after setting up a Custom Origin that points to the bucket domain name instead of using an S3 Origin. I'm still getting the same behavior where an invalid frontend link results in an S3 404 Key Error.

Comment: @briancaffey No worries, we are closer to a solution. You should also use `CustomOrigin` instead of a `S3Origin`. I will amend my original answer.

Comment: I updated my question once again with a full code sample from my CDK code. I think I'm getting close. By the way, when I tried creating an invalidation, I used `/*` for the paths, is that correct?

Comment: @briancaffey yeah, this will purge everything that's cached in CloudFront.

Comment: OK, I finally have the behavior I want. I was using the wrong domain name (S3 has a REST API and HTTP API for static sites). I'm adding my solution to the end of my question, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!